# SSIS job failure- Login timeout expired but package runs fine locally

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, database-administration

Description: "Login timeout expired".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. Code: 0xC00291EC     Source: Truncate Staging Execute SQL Task     Description: Failed to acquire connection "db_name". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.  End Error  Error: 2018-08-09 07:08:18.93     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: SSIS_CustomerHubStaging Connection manager "DB_NAME"

So my job has been failing consistently and I've tried almost everything, ex. changing delay validation to true,validate external metadata, etc. If I were to run this package locally using the same config file, the package would be executed without any errors. Please suggest any advice or help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the account executing the SQL Agent job has the right permissions to access the datasource from the connection manager of the Execute SQL Task that's returning the error?  This will include the SQL Server instance, as well as any objects within either the initial database or other databases that are accessed.  You can set the account to use in the "Run as" field of the job step that executes this package.

Comment: yup we've checked that multiple times and the account has all the right permissions. when i run the package on my local i use the same production server as when the SSIS job runs.